# Debian: what's the difference between "apt source" and "dget"?

Tags: debian, apt

There are multiple ways to download the source package -*.dsc (Debian Source Control) file. For example:

- apt source xxx
- dget xxx
- git clone (not related to this question)

What's the difference between "apt source" and "dget"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt source foo` will find the source package providing the `foo` binary package, download it, and extract it to the current directory. (See [the `apt-get` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/apt-get) for details.)

[`dget foo`](https://manpages.debian.org/dget) will download the `foo` *binary package* to the current directory. It doesn’t download the source package.

When given a URL, `dget` downloads the corresponding file; additionally, if the downloaded file is a `.dsc` or `.changes` file, it will download the other files referenced there, and extract the resulting source package.

Comment: what means "download the other files referenced there", dependency package?

Comment: No. `.dsc` and `.changes` files list the other files composing a source package (the `.orig` and `.debian` tarballs). Those are the other files referenced. `dget` doesn’t deal with dependencies.